# How to test macOS app in multiple version of macOS

Tags: swift, macos, testing, macos-big-sur

My app supports macOS 11.0+ and future version of macOS, but currently the version of my macOS is 12.0+, and the version of my Xcode is 13.0+. However, **I want to test my app's performance and some in app purchase (some are only available in macOS 11.0) under macOS 12.0**, how can I do that?

I have tried to install macOS Big Sur, however, TestFlight is only available in macOS 12.0+, I feel so powerless about it.